# Creating fields for max value at each level within segment/type combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope I can convey this clearly, been wracking my brain and can't figure it out. We have monthly historical data in which we calculate median spend for each type and level combination for our two segments.

I want to create two fields that display the most recent med spend value for that level by each segment and type combination.

I started with this, but I know it needs more.

```
        select Segment, Type, (select max([med spend]) from source where level = 'Gold') as 'Gold Spend',
    (select max([med spend]) from source where level = 'Silver') as 'Silver Spend'
        from source a
where a.date = (select max(b.date) from source b
where b.segment = a.segment and b.type = a.type)
```

**Source Table**

| Date | Segment | Type | Level | Med Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| December 2022 | A | 0 | Gold | **1303** |
| December 2022 | A | 1 | Gold | **1500** |
| December 2022 | A | 0 | Silver | **1000** |
| December 2022 | A | 1 | Silver | **1111** |
| November 2022 | A | 0 | Gold | 500 |
| November 2022 | A | 1 | Gold | 600 |
| November 2022 | A | 0 | Silver | 450 |
| November 2022 | A | 1 | Silver | 110 |
| December 2022 | B | 0 | Gold | **210** |
| December 2022 | B | 1 | Gold | **145** |
| December 2022 | B | 0 | Silver | **540** |
| December 2022 | B | 1 | Silver | **360** |
| November 2022 | B | 0 | Gold | 777 |
| November 2022 | B | 1 | Gold | 888 |
| November 2022 | B | 0 | Silver | 125 |
| November 2022 | B | 1 | Silver | 123 |

**Desired Output**

| Segment | Type | Silver Spend | Gold Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 1000 | 1303 |
| A | 1 | 1111 | 1000 |
| B | 0 | 540 | 210 |
| B | 1 | 360 | 145 |

Comment: Please look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are the combination of columns Date/Segment/Type/Level always distinct or may there be multiple rows with different Med Spend values? Do you want your results to only consider a specific month (December 2022, B, 1, Gold, 145) ignoring other months (November 2022, B, 1, Gold, 888). If more than one value is present, do you want the MAX(), SUM(), or the latest? If latest, do you have a sortable date field separate from the text month-year that you show in your sample data? (Your description states "most recent", your SQL uses MAX(), and the first answer posted as I write this is using SUM().)

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using. (Asking because SQL Server 2022 introduces the `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` functions that may suit your needs.)

Comment: @TN The combination of columns will always be distinct. I'd like them to always consider the latest date present in the data source. I am on version 18.12.1

Comment: FYI - You say "latest date" but the accepted answer is calculating the sum. (Check the results.)

Comment: @TN thanks for calling attention to that. I actually built in a line to my code to only pull the latest date from table1. So summing it works fine (since it's essentially summing a single value from the latest date).

Comment: If you have already pre-filtered the data, then all you really need is a PIVOT as in [This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/01c6j591).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  use an aggregation with `GROUP BY`

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    ([Date] varchar(13), [Segment] varchar(1), [Type] int, [Level] varchar(6), [Med Spend] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO table1
    ([Date], [Segment], [Type], [Level], [Med Spend])
VALUES
    ('December 2022', 'A', 0, 'Gold', 1303),
    ('December 2022', 'A', 1, 'Gold', 1500),
    ('December 2022', 'A', 0, 'Silver', 1000),
    ('December 2022', 'A', 1, 'Silver', 1111),
    ('November 2022', 'A', 0, 'Gold', 500),
    ('November 2022', 'A', 1, 'Gold', 600),
    ('November 2022', 'A', 0, 'Silver', 450),
    ('November 2022', 'A', 1, 'Silver', 110),
    ('December 2022', 'B', 0, 'Gold', 210),
    ('December 2022', 'B', 1, 'Gold', 145),
    ('December 2022', 'B', 0, 'Silver', 540),
    ('December 2022', 'B', 1, 'Silver', 360),
    ('November 2022', 'B', 0, 'Gold', 777),
    ('November 2022', 'B', 1, 'Gold', 888),
    ('November 2022', 'B', 0, 'Silver', 125),
    ('November 2022', 'B', 1, 'Silver', 123)
;
```

```
16 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
[Segment], [Type],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] = 'Silver' THEN  [Med Spend] ELSE 0 END) Siver_spent,
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] = 'Gold' THEN  [Med Spend] ELSe 0 END) Gold_spent
FROM table1
GROUP BY [Segment], [Type]
```

| Segment | Type | Siver_spent | Gold_spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 1450 | 1803 |
| B | 0 | 665 | 987 |
| A | 1 | 1221 | 2100 |
| B | 1 | 483 | 1033 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/51IG84pV)

Comment: This looks to accomplish what I'm trying to do perfectly. Thank you so much. I'll follow back up if I get tripped up. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A windowed ROW_NUMBER() function can be used to prioritize your spend values within each Segment/Type/Level context. From there you can group the results and use "conditional aggregation" to select the top value for each.

One change needed before this can work is to have a sortable date column in your source. A "Monthname-YYYY" column will not work.

```
SELECT Segment, Type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 'Silver' AND rn = 1 THEN [Med Spend] END) AS [Silver Spend],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 'Gold' AND rn = 1 THEN [Med Spend] END) AS [Gold Spend]
FROM (
    SELECT T.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.Segment, T.Type, T.Level ORDER BY T.Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM table1 T
) TN
GROUP BY Segment, Type
ORDER BY Segment, Type
```

Or, if you prefer, you can use a Common Table Expression (CTE) instead of a subquery:

```
; WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT T.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.Segment, T.Type, T.Level ORDER BY T.Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM table1 T
)
SELECT Segment, Type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 'Silver' AND rn = 1 THEN [Med Spend] END) AS [Silver Spend],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 'Gold' AND rn = 1 THEN [Med Spend] END) AS [Gold Spend]
FROM CTE1
GROUP BY Segment, Type
ORDER BY Segment, Type
```

Results:

| Segment | Type | Silver Spend | Gold Spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 1000 | 1303 |
| A | 1 | 1111 | 1500 |
| B | 0 | 540 | 210 |
| B | 1 | 360 | 145 |

The "1500" value is different from the OP expected results, but I believe these results are correct given the requested criteria.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gx2eVW0j).